# How to capture screenshots with Junit5 Custom annotations?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit5

I am trying to capture screenshots using custom annotation from junit 5 but no luck yet. Test is working fine but without capturing screenshots :

```
@Inherited
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@ResourceLock(value = SYSTEM_PROPERTIES, mode = READ)
@Target({ TYPE, METHOD, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Test
@Documented
public @interface UserTest {

}
```

Junit 5 class :

```
class WhenSearchingForTerms {
@Managed(driver = "chrome")
WebDriver driver;

@Steps
NavigateActions navigate;**strong text**
@UserTest()
void searchBySingleKeyword() {
navigate.toTheHomePage();        
  }
}
```

but when I am running same test without custom annotation its capturing screenshots. Below code capture screenshot but I want to capture screenshots with custom junit 5 annotation mentioned above. I am not sure what it is I need to do further. Can someone help me please?

```
class WhenSearchingForTerms {
    @Managed(driver = "chrome")
    WebDriver driver;

    @Steps
    NavigateActions navigate;
    @Test
    void searchBySingleKeyword() {
    navigate.toTheHomePage();        
      }
    }
```